# CocoaLumberjack in Swift, how to print line number and filne name

Tags: ios, swift, cocoalumberjack

I'm new to CocoaLumberjack and I get it to work on Swift following [this](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/issues/405). If I try to print logs doing:

```
DDLogDebug("Debug")
DDLogInfo("Info")
DDLogWarn("Warning")
DDLogVerbose("Verbose")
DDLogError("Error")
```

Everything works fine and I get all the levels printed as my `defaultDebugLevel` is DDLogLevel.Verbose.

But I can't find/find out how to print the line or the filename with the log. Any idea?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Maybe this will help [link](https://gist.github.com/stigi/505a1b036d4776e4bfe1)

Comment: mmm not helping me haha. Thanks :)

Comment: Recommend another nice Logger library: https://github.com/zhihuitang/SwiftMagic

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After some more research I found that you have to create a log formatter, this log formatter is a subclass of `DDDispatchQueueLogFormatter` and you have to override a function that receives a `DDLogMessage` and returns a `String`, for example:

```
import Foundation
import CocoaLumberjack.DDDispatchQueueLogFormatter

class LogFormatter: DDDispatchQueueLogFormatter {
  let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter

  override init() {
    dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.formatterBehavior = .Behavior10_4
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

    super.init()
  }

  override func formatLogMessage(logMessage: DDLogMessage!) -> String {
    let dateAndTime = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(logMessage.timestamp)
    return "\(dateAndTime) [\(logMessage.fileName):\(logMessage.line)]: \(logMessage.message)"
  }
}
```

Then you just have to add your formatter like this in your AppDelegate or wherever you are setting CocaLumberJack:

```
DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance().logFormatter = LogFormatter()
```

Hope it helps someone!

Comment: @Hugh please do not edit existing answers to add new code.  We don't want to put words into the original author's mouth.  Instead, add a new answer.

Answer (score 7):

Update for `CocoaLumberjack (3.1.0)`:

`import CocoaLumberjack.DDLog`

```
class LogFormatter: NSObject, DDLogFormatter {
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter

    override init() {
        dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS"

        super.init()
    }
    func format(message logMessage: DDLogMessage) -> String? {
        let dateAndTime = dateFormatter.string(from: logMessage.timestamp)
        return "\(dateAndTime) [\(logMessage.fileName):\(logMessage.line)]: \(logMessage.message)"
    }
}
```

`DDTTYLogger.sharedInstance.logFormatter = LogFormatter()`

Answer (score 3):

Andres's answer Updated for Swift 3 (with minor tweak of datetime format by [Hugh](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31431439/2))

```
import Foundation
import CocoaLumberjack.DDDispatchQueueLogFormatter

class LogFormatter: DDDispatchQueueLogFormatter {
    let dateFormatter: DateFormatter

    override init() {
        dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS"

        super.init()
    }

    override func format(message: DDLogMessage!) -> String {
        let dateAndTime = dateFormatter.string(from: message.timestamp)
        return "\(dateAndTime) [\(message.fileName!) \(message.function!):\(message.line)] \(message.message ?? "")"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#import "CustomFormatter.h"

@implementation CustomFormatter : NSObject

- (NSString *)formatLogMessage:(DDLogMessage *)logMessage {
    NSString *logLevel;
    switch (logMessage->_flag) {
        case DDLogFlagError    : logLevel = @"[E]"; break;
        case DDLogFlagWarning  : logLevel = @"[W]"; break;
        case DDLogFlagInfo     : logLevel = @"[I]"; break;
        case DDLogFlagDebug    : logLevel = @"[D]"; break;
        default                : logLevel = @"[V]"; break;
    }

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%lu %@ | %@ ", logMessage->_fileName, (unsigned long)logMessage->_line, logLevel, logMessage->_message];
}

@end
```